# Objects changing on inspection while debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, castle-windsor, fluentvalidation

I'm experiencing a very strange problem. In my project there are Purchases and Sales, Model classes. Each of these class is linked to a UnitOfMeasure model.

Purchases have a Uom
Purchases can have many Sales, each sale has a Uom

When an update to a Sale is made through a WebService call to a sale: A call to the database builds a Sale object, updates the sale (no longer selling 10kg, but 10 US Tons), then it's passed to the Fluenvalidator who does a check to see if this much stock is available.

```
 RuleFor(sii => sii)
            .Must(HaveEnoughStockForSale)
            .WithMessage("The sales invoice...");
```

This is where it gets very strange. I put a break point inside the HaveEnoughStockForSale and everything looks fine.
Everything is paused, I mouse over the sale SaleUom and the debugger tells me it's (correctly) US Tons.
I mouse over the Sale Uom and it tells me it's kgs, but the moment I inspect the Purchase Uom, it has overwritten the Sale UOM to kgs too.

[image: Uom Change]

I've never seen an object I'm about to write to a database change after you inspect something while debugging.

[image]

Can anyone help me with what is going on here. I'm not sure if it's the FluentValidator, Windsor or the entity framework